# Runnable Function Depending on Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

In Java, how can I have a Runnable class that, depending on its constructor, selects its function?

For example:

```
Class A implements Runnable {

    public A(int var) {
        //things go here
    }

    public A(int var1, String var2) {
        //things go here
    }

    public void run() {
        //do (a) if Constructor A(int var)
        //do (b) if Constructor A(int var1, String var2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would setup a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) Pattern:

```
class A implements Runnable {

    private final ExecutionStrategy strategy;

    public A(int var) {   
        strategy = new FooStrategy();
    }

    public A(int var1, String var2) {
        strategy = new BarStrategy();
    }

    public void run() {
        strategy.exec();
    }

    interface ExecutionStrategy { 
        public void exec();
    }

    private class FooStrategy implements ExecutionStrategy { 
        @Override
        public void exec() { 
        //implement me
        }
    }

    private class BarStrategy implements ExecutionStrategy { 
        @Override
        public void exec() { 
        //implement me
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was going to suggest much the same *except* that I would keep things simple: why not define anonymous Runnable's so you can stick to the Runnable interface throughout? No need to introduce more "types" to keep track of inside the head... (Remember this is about approximating functions.)

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste.  I think adding new types actually reduces code complexity if they're properly documented and organized.

Comment: Also notice this approach does not require any conditional code.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
class A implements Runnable {
  int constructor;

public A(int var) {
    //things go here
    constructor = 1;
}

public A(int var1, String var2) {
    //things go here
    constructor = 2; 
}

public void run() {
    if (constructor == 1) ...
    if (Constructor == 2) ...
}
```

}

But I would recommend using polymorphism. It looks like these are two different classes of objects.

Comment: @drum - yeah - use an `if` or `case` statement: the same way you selectively run any piece of code.